# Styling the border with a very specific shape around an image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Very new to web dev so apologies in advance if I sound like I do not know what I am doing. Trying to have this type of border around an image but cannot manage to do this with that specific corner. Any ideas?[check the link please cannot embed images into this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSfr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two blocks. you can use something like this(picture on the red one)

```css
.bg
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: solid green;
}

.image
{
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
<div class="image">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```